# creating a list of all S3 files that have been overwritten at least once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have Bucket Versioning enabled on a particular S3 bucket and I'd like to be able to find all files that have been modified more than once.

I could iterate through every item in the bucket and look at that files individual attributes but I have 1.5 million files in my bucket and that'd take a long time. I don't suppose there's a way to do a performant search for files that have been modified more than once?

Comment: No, there is not "performant" search for that. You need to list all objects and versions.

Comment: If a slight delay is acceptable, you can setup and generate an [S3 Inventory report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) that includes all versions of an object, so you can parse one file instead of making thousands of API calls to enumerate all of the objects and their versions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several AWS services that will do what you need.

[AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) will find resources that have changed.

[AWS CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) can be used to find changes to objects, including versions.

[AWS CloudWatch Events](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/events/) can be used to find changes to objects, including versions.

[AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/orgs/) can be used to audit changes.

None of these can be applied retroactively.

Comment: I don't think AWS Config applies to S3 objects, CloudTrail only works if you enable data events which will be expensive, not sure what Organizations have to do with anything here. And generally none of this works retroactively.